# Differential equation problem, STEP II (2000) question 8.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please google the problem sheet ("STEP past papers", leads you directly to mathsorchard website with all past papers; second link)

I have no problems with the first part of the question, my solution goes like this:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -4xe^{-x^2}(y+3)^{1/2}$$

Integrating by parts:

$$2e^{-x^2}=2(y+3)^{1/2}+c$$

Given the initial condition, $c=-4$

I then arrive at the following (expressing $y$ in terms of x):

$$y=e^{-x^2}(e^{-x^2}+4)+1$$

Now $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x^2}(e^{-x^2}+4)+1 = 1$, as required.

The second part I cannot seem to make work. Similarly to the first part I proceed with integration by parts, obtaining:

$$\frac{1}{12} e^{6x^2}=\frac{1}{k}(y+3)^k +c$$

Given that $k$, is not some function of $x$.

I "hide" the constant in $e$: $\frac{A}{12}e^{6x^2}=\frac{1}{k}(y+3)^k$. Massaging the terms to get $e^{-3x^2}y$, I obtain:

$$e^{-3x^2}y=\frac{12(y+3)^ky}{Ake^{9x^2}}$$

And now to constrain the $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{12(y+3)^ky}{Ake^{9x^2}}$, I need to make $k=e^{-9x^2}$, but I cannot do this because then the integral that I have performed is meaningless. Thus, I am stuck..

**EDIT: I got the answer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We obtain the following answer by integration by parts:

$\frac{1}{12} e^{6x^2}=\frac{1}{k}(y+3)^k +c$

Both sides have to approach infinity similarly to be balanced, i.e.

$y^k \approx \frac{k}{12} e^{6x^2}$, ignoring the constants.

Or

$$y \approx (\frac{k}{12})^{1/k} (e^{6x^2})^{1/k}$$
Now divide by $e^{3x^2}$.

$e^{-3x^2}y=(\frac{k}{12})^{1/k} (e^{x^2(6-3k)/k})$

The only way to make that RHS bounded is by setting $k=2$ so that we get $e^0$. Hence, $k=2$ and the bounding value of $e^{-3x^2}y$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.

This is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

i think your solution is wrong, i have got this here $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to \frac{1}{4} e^{-2 x^2} \left(c_1^2 e^{2 x^2}+4 c_1
   e^{x^2}-12 e^{2 x^2}+4\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: redone the question and obtained exactly same answer again.

Comment: But how did you get this?

Comment: Dr. Graubner, I respect many of your answers, but you really need to stop giving just answers without even a hint of how to get the answer. Such "answers" as these belong as comments. Please use your considerable skills to write better answers.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer.

Comment: then prove it that it is not the correct answer